# How to submit a user profile form through ajax?

Tags: 7, users

I want to submit the user profile form through ajax.

I see the ajax_register module but it does not support the user profile form. Is there any contrib module which I can use?

Or this can done custom. But with custom approach I have to look for the form validation also?

Answer (score 0):

Below module will help you

**[Modal forms (with ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms)**

> Modal forms make use of the modal feature in the ctools module to open
>   some common forms in a modal window.
>
> ```
> Log in (modal_forms/nojs/login)
> Request new password (modal_forms/nojs/password)
> Create new account (modal_forms/nojs/register)
> Contact (modal_forms/nojs/contact)
> Comment (modal_forms/nojs/comment/reply/%node)
> Webform (modal_forms/nojs/webform/%node)
> ```
>
> Function that rewrite normal links to modal forms links (except for
>   webforms) can be activated on the modules configuration page

Comment: I think it does not support the user profile form.